# Successive execution of two commands in different folders

Tags: scripts, automation

I am really new to ubuntu and I have a small question.

I have two different commands that have to be repeated 4 times each (so 8 overall executions)

These CommandA.sh and CommandB.sh are always located in their working directory (each working directory is preparing the files in the folder for processing)

So how can I write a bash command that technically:

1. "goes" into the first working directory
2. executes CommandA.sh
3. wait until CommandA.sh is finished
4. executes CommandB.sh
5. waits until CommandB.sh is finished
6. "goes" into the second working directory
7. redoes the steps 2-5
8. "goes" into the third working directory

rinse and repeat for the last working folder....

Is that "easily" doable, or does it require a big amount of scripting?

Thank you for you help !

Sincerely
Max

Comment: 1. Are the folder names relevant to each other? ex *folder1, folder2, folder3, ...* or do they have completely different names? 2. Do you need the script too?

Comment: thanks for the reply, in this case they are all in one folder together and are enumerated P71, P72 P3 etc.

Comment: Do you need the script itself or just instructions on how to do it yourself?

Comment: I prefer to learn it, so that i am better equiped next time a situation like that comes around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# We define an array (folders) that contains the folder names
folders[0]="first folder name"
folders[1]="second folder name"
folders[2]="third folder name"
folders[3]="fourth folder name"

for oneFolder in "${folders[@]}"; do
    cd "$oneFolder" # changes to specified folder
    commandA && commandB # Executes commandA and if it's successful, executes commandB
    # The loop continues until the last folder in the array is reached.
done

echo
```

If you need more than four folders, you can add more in the array, following the same pattern (*folders[x]=""*).

**WARNING**: This is a very simple bash script that performs no error checking. It's up to you to incorporate the necessary checks in *commandA* and *commandB*. If an error occurs and it's not handled, it will occur again and again in all the folders specified in the array.
**WARNING 2**: You should use complete paths in every folder name, for example */home/user/folder1*. Not just the name, in order to make sure the script will locate all the folders correctly.

A backup of each folder would be wise before you use a script.

Comment: Thank you very much !
There error checks are done manually before the script is incorporated, so i know that commands run through!

Thank you very much again! it will help me out tremendously later tonight !